# Rails 4 many-to-many through relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through

I have 3 tables Jobs, Counties and Countyization.

County has:

```
has_many :countyizations
has_many :jobs, :through => :countyizations
```

Countyization has:

```
belongs_to :county
belongs_to :job
```

Job has:

```
has_many :countyizations
has_many :counties, :through => :countyizations
```

I am using simple_forms and have the following in my create/edit form.

```
<%= f.association :counties, :as => :check_boxes, :collection => County.all.sort, :selected => @job.counties, :label => false %>
```

This does generate checkboxes of all the counties I have in the database,  I can check them, but when I create or edit a record the "countyization" associations don't take.  Do I need to add something to the "params.require" section of my job controller?   I have been working on this for days and am very frustrated.  Any help at all is greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

you need to actually build relationship in controller between two models (jobs and county).

in your jobs_controller.rb add

```
def create
    @job = Job.new(job_params)
    @job.counties.build
    if @job.save 
       ..
    else 
      ..
    end
end

private

  def job_params
    params.require(:job).permit(:your_param_1, :your_param_2)
  end
```